# Why do I get "_next/image?url=example.com/assets/photo.png" when I try to load external image from another domain?

Tags: next.js, next-images

I'd like to load pictures from other domain that is "api.domain.com".

I have configured `next.config.js` like this in order to avoid external `URL` error.

```
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "http",
        hostname: "api.example.app",
        port: ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I inspect image what I see is that it's setting `srcset="/_next/image?url=http://example.com/assets/photo.png"`

How can I bypass adding `_next/image` as prefix?

P.s please do not recommend me using `img` tag.

Comment: Why do you want to bypass the nextjs `Image` improvements but not use `img`?

Comment: @grekier I'm actually trying to understand why Image from Next is rendering broken image. Assuming it's because of `/_next/image ` maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js automatically optimize images when you use `<Image />` from `next/image`.

Let's say you have a `.png` image with 1MB size, and its source is `http://example.com/assets/photo.png`. Next.js will generate some variants of the image with more modern formats e.g. `.webp` in different sizes, 0.1 MB, 0.5 MB, and 1 MB. it will collect any `src` you passed to `<Image />` (and exists in the `remotePatterns`) to change the `src` to the Next.js built-in optimization loader `/_next/image?url=${src}`. This way it will respond with the suitable image variant for the device.

Reed more:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/images

You can make your custom loader:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#loader

Comment: Thanks man! I have already got the issue. Our lisence for server is expired. That's why it was not fetching the pictures. I tried with this config with other random picture from online and is working pretty fine.